# How to pass multiple inputs from HTML to Python

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

I want to pass multiple input datas from my HTML to Python with Flask. It is dynamic, so depending on the value chosen, different number of inputs appear.

```
<div class="inner-flex-box">
        <div class="black">
            Feed times and schedule
        </div>
        <div class="black">
            <form method="POST">
                <input type="number" name="numberOfFeedTimes" value=0>
                <input type="submit" value="Choose number of feedings">
            </form>

            <form method="POST">
                {% for i in range (0, number) %}
                    <input type="time" name="feedTimes">
                {% endfor %}
                <input type="submit">
            </form>

        </div>
</div>
```

I am using the html as shown, and the Python script is below, which saves the data recieved to a database.

```
     @app.route('/settings', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
        def settings():
            conn = get_db_connetion()
            number = 0
            feedTimes = []
            try:
                number = conn.execute('SELECT numberOfFeeds FROM db').fetchone()[0]
            except TypeError as e:
                print(e)
                print("\nThe database position is empty!")
        
            if request.method == 'POST':
                number = int(request.form['numberOfFeedTimes'])
                feedTimes = request.form.getlist("feedTimes")
                
                conn.execute('UPDATE db SET numberofFeeds = ?', str(number))
                try:
                    print("The number is: ", conn.execute('SELECT numberOfFeeds FROM db').fetchone()[0])
                except TypeError as e:
                    print (e)
                    conn.execute("INSERT INTO db (numberOfFeeds) VALUES (?)", str(number))
                    
        
                conn.commit()
```

My question is, how can I pass data from these inputs to save them in a list of a dictionary?

Answer (score -1):

Your HTML template didn't specify the endpoint of the FORM submission. Therefore, it didn't send the data to your backend after user click submit.

To improve it, you can add the `action` tag.

```
<form method="POST" action="/settings">
```

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't help. I get a "Bad Request" respons.

Comment: Could you share the response code? 404 not found? or else?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Aug/2022 12:10:51] "POST /settings HTTP/1.1" 400 -

Comment: Could you try to comment out the line:  feedTimes = request.form.getlist("feedTimes")? I suspect this line causes the problem. In your POST form request, you only send data numberOfFeedTimes, but not feedTimes. You are trying to get a non-existed element from request. It can cause problem.

Comment: That's what I want to achive. I want to pass the feed times to the script. The numberOfFeedsTimes works well.